# .net Core / Blazor : @onkeypress="@(e => OnKeyPressEvent(e))" does not work as it should when app is deployed to IIS:

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core, blazor

when debugging, the event fires on "Enter", but when the application is published on IIS, it only work's at a times. I have noticed that when it does not works, it places a "?" at the end of the URL it tries to reach out:
"/data?"

Any help here is highly appreciated. 
thanks

````
<input type="text"  @bind-value="@Tags" @bind-value:event="oninput" @onkeypress="@(e => OnKeyPressEvent(e))" /> ```

@Code{
    void OnKeyPressEvent(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {

        if (args.Key == "Enter")
        {
            DoSomething-OK();            
        }
    }
}
````

Comment: Could you please share your code and show how you are doing that?

Comment: Please see above. :)

Comment: There is no url in your code. Describe it better.

Comment: Also, the normal way to bind an event: `@onkeypress="OnKeyPressEvent"`

Comment: The code looks largely ok-ish, it could very well be some problem in DoSomething-OK(). Write up a proper [mcve].

Comment: After some deep testing sessions, we have found that the code works ok depending oh how fast you type / press "Enter". 
Seems like the @bind-value="@Tags" takes quite some time to assign the value to the variable, if you hit "Enter" before it completes this process (may take up to 2 seconds for what we've observed) it won't pass the complete string as parameter. 

More research is needed; however.

Comment: 2 seconds is excessive. Is this a Wasm app or a Server based app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Solution I found to the issue: 
1- The Form needs to be set to False on submit, that way it wont reload the full component.

```
<form class="SearchBarExample" onsubmit="return false">
<input type="text" size="100" placeholder="Search here..."@bind-value="@Tags" @bind-value:event="oninput"@onkeyup="OnKeyUPEvent" />
</form>
```